# Java String Contains

Tags: java, string

I know that there are other questions like this and I did have a look at them but it did not work for me.

```
String one= "ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES ROLENOMINATIONS"; 
String two = "ROLENOMINATIONS ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES";
if(one.contains(two) || two.contains(one))
{
    System.out.println("Contains");
}
else
    System.out.println("Doesn't Contain");
```

This is my code and even though one contains two and two also contains one, it always prints that string one doesn't contain string two

Comment: No String contains another in your case.

Comment: Contains means "is a substring of", one does _not_ contain two and two does _not_ contain one.

Comment: Why do you think one contains two or vice versa?

Comment: In the direction of finding the solution, I suggest you copy the two strings into two different lists using StringTokenizer and then check each string contains in other list and decide your output accordingly.

Comment: Those two are not same, so why it will show it is same.

Comment: Everyone calm down, I made a mistake. Thanks for helping me out with it though.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
String one= "ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES ROLENOMINATIONS"; 
String two = "ROLENOMINATIONS ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES";
String oneArray[] = one.split("\\s+");
String twoArray[] = one.split("\\s+");
Arrays.sort(oneArray);
Arrays.sort(twoArray);
if(Arrays.equals(oneArray, twoArray))
{
    System.out.println("Contains");
}
else
    System.out.println("Doesn't Contain");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're comparing the whole String, and apparently you seem to be thinking it checks every substring split at the space which honestly doesn't work that way (it would be unintuitive too).

So,

```
String one= "ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES ROLENOMINATIONS"; 
String two = "ROLENOMINATIONS ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES";

String[] oneSplit = one.split(" ");
String[] twoSplit = two.split(" ");
boolean contains = false;
for(int i = 0; i < oneSplit.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < twoSplit.length; j++)
    {
        if(oneSplit[i].contains(twoSplit[j])
        {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(contains)
{
    System.out.println("Contains");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Doesn't Contain");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contains() method returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values. And in your code, the sequence of characters in each string is different from the other hence why in your code it returns false and prints that string one doesn't contain string two. The key thing here is the sequence of characters in each string.

Answer (score 0):

**.contains()** function did not check they have common words or not.
  It's check whether your one string is subset of other.
  in your case both strings are not subset of each other

```
    String one= "ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES ROLENOMINATIONS"; 
    String two= "ROLEMOVIES";
    if(one.contains(two) || two.contains(one))
    {
        System.out.println("Contains");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Doesn't Contain");
```

Now it will print "Contains".

Plz read [here](http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/Java-Data-Type/string/contain.htm) in detail about .contain()

Answer (score 0):

those two string are not same.

```
String one= "ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES ROLENOMINATIONS"; 
String two = "ROLENOMINATIONS ROLEAWARDS ROLEMOVIES";
 if(one.contains(two) || two.contains(one))
        one.contains(two) will be  true if two is a subset of one
        two.contains(one)   will be  true if one is a subset of two
```

So the result is correct . as none of them is a subset of another.