# How to check if a string has a specified character?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android studio and kotlin. I need to find a way to check if a string contains a char, which is, in this case, "/"
I want to form a piece of code in the following manner:

```
if (string input contains a character "/") = true {
<code>
}
else{
<code>
}
```

Please tell me how to do this, and if possible, give me the code I'll need to specify as the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java String Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955708/java-string-contains)

Comment: `if ('/' in myString) { //...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238456/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-kotlin)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos No, I need the code for Kotlin and how to structure it. .contains() is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use contains, like this:

```
val a = "hello/"
val b = a.contains("/")
```

When the string has the character will return true.

Comment: I get it, but It's not working in if..else
Is this code correct?:  if (RAWlength.contains("/") = true) || (RAWbreadth.contains("/") = true){.....}

Comment: Try something like this:
val a = "hello/"
val b = a.contains("/")
if (b) {
//return result when b is true
} else {
// return when b is false.
}

Comment: @DeathVenom it's because in the piece of code that you shared you are not doing an comparison, you're doing an assignment. Use `==` instead of `=`; or simply removed `== true` altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there seems to be an error with the usage of 'or'. It shows the first condition as correct but says the second condition has an error (kotlin)

Comment: Finally got it!! I had to put the whole thing with the || under a single paranthesis. Thanks for your help everyone!!